# Python programming changing a specific value in file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with concerning my code:

```
with open('Premier_League.txt', 'r+') as f:
    data = [int(line.strip()) for line in f.readlines()] # [1, 2, 3]
    f.seek(0)

    i = int(input("Add your result! \n"))

    data[i] += 1  # e.g. if i = 1, data now [1, 3, 3]

    for line in data:
        f.write(str(line) + "\n")

    f.truncate()
    print(data)
```

The code works that the file "Premier_League.txt" that contains for example:

```
1
2
3
```

where `i=1`
gets converted to and saved to already existing file (the previous info gets deleted)

```
1
3
3
```

**My problem is that I want to chose a specific value in a matris (not only a vertical line) for example:**

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

where i would like to change it to for example:

```
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

When I run this trough my program this appears:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 1 1 1'
```

***So my question is: how do I change a specific value in a file that contains more than a vertical line of values?***

Comment: Question: why `0 1 0 0` and not say `0 0 1 0` or any other combination?

Comment: No you should be able to change it to both, its just going in and changing **a specific value in the file** , therefore it can be both `0 1 0 0` or    `0 0 1 0` or why not    `0 1 1 0`

Comment: This is the very definition of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are approaching the whole thing wrong.

Comment: Maybe consider providing column names and handle it like a csv instead? It might make things much easier to handle as well when wanting to change data.

Comment: Also you prompt the user to *add his result* but instead you simply use the input to jump to the corresponding line and increment the content by 1..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are not handling the increased number of dimensions properly. Try something like this;

```
with open('Premier_League.txt', 'r+') as f:
    # Note this is now a 2D matrix (nested list)
    data = [[int(value) for value in line.strip().split()] for line in f ]
    f.seek(0)

    # We must specify both a column and row
    i = int(input("Add your result to column! \n"))
    j = int(input("Add your result to row! \n"))

    data[i][j] += 1 # Assign to the index of the column and row

    # Parse out the data and write back to file
    for line in data:
        f.write(' '.join(map(str, line)) + "\n")

    f.truncate()
    print(data)
```

You could also use a generator expression to write to the file, for example;

```
# Parse out the data and write back to file
f.write('\n'.join((' '.join(map(str, line)) for line in data)))
```

instead of;

```
# Parse out the data and write back to file
for line in data:
    f.write(' '.join(map(str, line)) + "\n")
```

Comment: And just a question, the two examples; do they basically act the same?

Comment: Is it just that the first one is simpler written? ^^

Comment: The first one is one line less code, but they basically do the same thing.

Comment: If you want to get technical I suppose the second one uses more write operations but less memory, I prefer it just because I think it's more elegant, but it's harder to understand to I included both.

Answer (score 1):

First up, you are trying to parse the string '0 0 0 0' as an int, that's the error you are getting. To fix this, do:

```
data = [[int(ch) for ch in line.strip().split()] for line in f.readlines()]
```

This will create a 2D array, where the first index corresponds to the row, and the second index corresponds to the column. Then, you would probably want the user to give you two values, instead of a singular `i` since you are trying to edit in a 2D array.

Edit:
So your following code will look like this:

```
i = int(input("Add your result row: \n"))
j = int(input("Add your result column: \n"))

data[i][j] += 1  
# For data = [[1,2,1], [2,3,2]], and user enters i = 1
# and j = 0, the new data will be [[1,2,1], [3,3,2]]
```

Comment: I am not compleatly sure I understand you. Do you mean I should change my       `data = [int(line.strip()) for line in f.readlines()] # [1, 2, 3]` into `data = [[int(ch) for ch in line.strip().split(' ')] for line in f.readlines()]`, but the program tells me that: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: Sorry there was a slight bug, it should be `split()` not `split(' ')`. But the user Tom Wyllie has already addressed it